# Showing report in Attachments field -odoo14

Tags: pdf, report, odoo, attachment

I try to save automatically a printed pdf in attachments, but I got this error :

**The report's template 'test' is wrong, please contact your administrator. 


Can not separate file to save as attachment because the report's template does not contain the attributes 'data-oe-model' and 'data-oe-id' on the div with 'article' classname.**

this is my Code:

```
<report id="report_action_test"
        string="test"
        model="stock.picking"
        report_type="qweb-pdf"
        name="Vija_waybill_stock_picking_report.new_report_stock_waybill"
        file="Vija_waybill_stock_picking_report.new_report_stock_waybill"
        attachment_use="True"
        attachment="'test-' + object.name + '.pdf'"
/>
```

template :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<odoo>
    <template id="new_report_stock_waybill">
        <t t-call="web.html_container">
            <t t-call="web.basic_layout">
                <div class="page" t-att-data-oe-model="o and o._name" t-att-data-oe-id="o and o.id">
                    <t t-raw="0"/>
                    <span>
                        this is a test
                    </span>
                </div>
            </t>
        </t>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

Comment: The error message specifies that the template does not contain the attributes **on the div with 'article' classname.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in:

```
<t t-call="web.basic_layout">
```

so it shoud not be in the xml file neither "web.basic_layout" nor "web.external_layout".

the right code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<odoo>
    <template id="new_report_stock_waybill3">
        <t t-call="web.html_container">
            <div class="page">
                <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">
                    <div class="article" t-att-data-oe-model="doc and doc._name"
                         t-att-data-oe-id="doc and doc.id">
                        <p>test</p>
                    </div>
                </t>
            </div>
        </t>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score -1):

in this line should be like this

```
attachment="'test- %s' + %(object.name) + '.pdf'"
```

Comment: I tried but it's still the error

Comment: You probably pasted the wrong code, it is an invalid syntax (``+ %``) and you don't need to specify the file extension (`+ '.pdf'`)

Comment: its type file pdf so you dont need ,pdf